# Why does the Haskell PVP describe new functions as non-breaking?

Tags: haskell, versioning, compatibility

Let's say I have the following code

```
module A where

  x :: Int 
  x = 5

module Main where

  import A
  import Lib
  
  main :: IO ()
  main = print (x + y)
```

and in an external library

```
module Lib where

  y :: Int
  y = 10
```

All well and good, the library is at v0.1.0.0 and I include it with bounds `mylib == 0.1.*`

Now, the name `x :: Int` is added to the export list of MyLib and a new release is out. It's version is v0.1.1.0, as suggested in [the PVP flowchart](https://pvp.haskell.org/#decision-tree):

> In this case, only [...] functions [...] were added to the library's exported interface. No breakage [...] could result

How is this assertion correct? Surely my code no longer compiles. Since it doesn't know where to pull `x` from.

Comment: It's not `mylib`'s interface *alone* that causes the breakage, which is what a major-number bump would indicate. People *not* using `A` won't see a problem with the introduction of `x`. (I.e, it's not `mylib`'s fault you aren't using `import qualified A` :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prevent breakage with a defensive importing style. [The Haskell wiki has an article about it](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import_modules_properly):

> We recommend to focus on the following two forms of import:
>
> ```hs
> import qualified Very.Special.Module as VSM
> import Another.Important.Module (printf, (<|>), )
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```hs
> import Very.Special.Module
> import Another.Important.Module hiding (open, close, )
> ```

And the PVP rules are one of the reasons they advocate for the explicit style.